# Trigger multipe 'transitions' at the same time

Tags: html, css, reactjs, css-animations, css-transitions

Does anybody know how to play transitions from two separate Components
with the same styling at the same time.

Here is a video, which shows my problem. 
https://youtu.be/WNu4Mdfn98U

Important CSS Parts

```css
.Container_Active .Description {
  max-height: 500px;
  margin-top: 5px;
  color: var(--ifm-color-on-primary);
  transition: max-height 1000ms ease-in; /* Transiation 1 */
}

.Description {
  max-height: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-size: var(--ifm-font-size-18);
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 1000ms ease-out; /* Transiation 2 */
}
```

Important HMTL Parts

```
 <div
      className={clsx(styles.Container, {
        [styles.Container_Active]: active,
      })}
     >
</div>
```

```
 <SectionRightItem
    key={i}
    title={section.title}
    description={section.description}
    onClick={() => {
      setIndex(i);
    }}
    icon={section.icon}
    active={index === i}
/>
```

My goal is that the one element slowly shows the description and the other element slowly hides the expanded description at the same time.
But somehow the transitions are played in a row, although they are triggered at the same time.

Thank you ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually your animation is starting at the same time, but the problem is that you use the transition of `max-height` with a value that's too high, so the transition will start from the height of `500px` to `0px`, but your content height doesn't even reach half of it, so it appears like there's a delay between your transition

To resolve the problem, you can lower the value of `.Container_Active` to match your actual description height, or change it to `height` rather than `max-height` with an **average height** of your actual description

Here's a simple snippet about the difference between `max-height` (light blue) and `height` (red) for the transition which makes your transition looks like it's delayed, both `height` / `max-height` is set to `0` when not opened and `10em` when opened

```js
$(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    $('div').toggleClass('open');
  }, 1500);
});
```

```css
div {
  position: absolute;
}

#front {
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: lightblue;
  transition: max-height 1000ms ease-in-out;
  padding-left: 3em;
}

#front.open {
  max-height: 10em;
  transition: max-height 1000ms ease-in-out;
}

#back {
  height: 0;
  background: red;
  transition: height 1000ms ease-in-out;
  opacity: .75;
}

#back.open {
  height: 10em;
  transition: height 1000ms ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='front' class='open'>
Hello World Welcome<br/>World</br>Welcome
</div>
<div id='back' class='open'>
BACK
</div>
```

Comment: ahh.. thanks.. that sounds very logical, no idea why I didn't think of it..
I am not using the direct height because it's not possible to animate an auto height.. (See stackoverflow question below) ^^
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508605/how-can-i-transition-height-0-to-height-auto-using-css
thanks for your help ;D

Comment: @BennoDev yes you can't animate using the height of `inherit` or `auto`, that's why usually I prefer to set the `height` for the `open state` with the **average height** of all description, though for some little description it may appear blank, but it will preserve the height of all the description the same and the animation will flow smoothly :D